# Handling gesture event on elements within Collection View Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

How can I handle gesture events (taps, in my case) that are made within different elements inside a Collection View Cell?

I am using a collection view that is built using a custom cell. This custom cell includes the following elements:

- a UILabel
- a UIImageView
- a Button

If the user taps on the ImageView, then the user will be displayed a larger version of the image. If the user taps on the Button, then the image will be deleted in the database. So I need a way to a) detected which cell has been tapped within the collection view (similar to the functionality provided by the method *didDeselectItemAtIndexPath* and b) distinguish between the elements that can be tapped within the cell.

In the case of the tap to the UIImageView, I am trying to catch the tap and identify on which cell that was done by the following code within the *cellForItemAtIndexPath* method of the collection view:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    PostCellView *postCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PostCellView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(!postCell){
        postCell = [[PostCellView alloc]init];
    }

    long row = indexPath.row;
    PostModel *post = [self.newsfeedPosts objectAtIndex:row];
    NSURL *posterUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:post.media[@"poster"]];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *getPosterImage = [[NetworkHelper getInstance].session dataTaskWithURL:posterUrl completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIImage *posterImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            postCell.posterImageView.image = posterImage;

//here is where I try to handle the tap event, if it happens on the uiimabeview
            UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(posterTapDetected:)];
            [tapGestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];
            [postCell.posterImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];                               
        });
    }];
    [getPosterImage resume];

    return postCell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your collection view is a single section, you could add a tag to your `UIImageView` to represent the `UIImageView`'s row and thus cell, ex.

```
UIImage *posterImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
postCell.posterImageView.image = posterImage;
postCell.posterImageView.tag = row; // <-- add tag
```

Then identify the row in `posterTapDetected:`, ex:

```
- (void)posterTapDetected:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
    NSLog(@"row %d tapped", (int)gesture.view.tag);
}
```

As for distinguishing between the different elements that can be tapped within your cell, if each element's gesture recognizer is linked to a different method, identifying the element tapped wouldn't require any necessary extra work since each different element's tap gesture would be processed by each view's corresponding `UITapGestureRecognizer` action method.